# my android emulator is not working only showing this screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator

my android emulator is not working but app is running in my mobile [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Lks.png).it was working till night .i it only this screen but not working further but it is running right in mobile. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: check the logs in logcat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.